# Why is the compiler allowing me to cast one implementing class to another?

Tags: java, inheritance, downcast

So I was messing around with down-casting, trying to find what works and what doesn't. I have three classes: a base class `Animal`, and two derived classes `Dog` and `Cat`:

```
private class Animal {
}

private class Dog extends Animal {
}

private class Cat extends Animal {
}
```

The following code isn't allowed by the compiler for an obvious reason:

```
Dog dog = s.new Dog();
Cat cat = (Cat) dog;
```

This is because I'm casting one derived class to another derived class, which isn't possible. However, if I make `Animal` an interface type and `Cat` an interface type, then suddenly the compiler accepts it and doesn't say any problem, even though it isn't possible.

```
private interface Animal {

}

private class Dog implements Animal {

}

private interface Cat extends Animal {

}
```

As soon as I run the same code as before, it gives me an error, as expected.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the interface `Cat` is not an implementation, just a spec for an implementation which does not differ from interface `Animal` (yet).  So, there is nothing wrong with casting a dog to a `Cat` interface.

Comment: The compiler allows you to cast anything to anything; whether that works at runtimne is a different matter. A cast is you telling the compiler I know better and this thing you think is a `Foo` is also a `Bar`.

Comment: I corrected your rather confused terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is allowed is because it is perfectly possible for another class to exist, like this:

```
class CatDog extends Dog implements Cat {
}
```

Because such a class *could* exist, it is legal to cast an object of any (non-`final`) type to any interface type.

Comment: Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CatDog  :-)